# Array.prototype.find to search an Object in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, ecmascript-6

I am using Array.prototype.find to search an Object Person in an Array. I would like use the id to find this Object. I've been reading about the method find (ES6) but I don't know why my code is wrong.

This is my code:

```
AddresBook.prototype.getPerson = function (id) {

    return this.lisPerson.find(buscarPersona, id);

};

function buscarPersona(element, index, array) {
    if (element.id === this.id) {
        return element;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the `id` directly as the [`thisArg` parameter to `.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), but inside `buscarPersona` you expect `this` to be an object with a `.id` property. So either

- pass an object:

  ```
  lisPerson.find(buscarPersona, {id});
  function buscarPersona(element, index, array) {
      return element.id === this.id;
  }
  ```
- use `this` directly:

  ```
  lisPerson.find(buscarPersona, id);
  function buscarPersona(element, index, array) {
      // works in strict mode only, make sure to use it
      return element.id === this;
  }
  ```
- just pass a closure

  ```
  lisPerson.find(element => element.id === id);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

A dirty solution could be added the `last_id` in the `AddressBook's` Prototype.

So your code would be the following

```
AddressBook.prototype.getPerson = function(id){
    this.last_id = id;
    return this.lisPerson.find(buscarPersona,this);
}
function buscarPersona(element){
    if(element.id === this.last_id){
        return element;
    }else{
        return false;   
    }
}
```